# Why browser doesnt recognize jquery when <script src="...jquery.js> is on a html page served by Google App Engine (from a http request)?

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest

`jquery.js` source code is not being recognised by browser using my `page.html` served by Google App Engine as a `http:some_request` to the SDK, ***BUT*** when I load the *exact same* `page.html` into the browser directly from my local hard drive as `jquery.js` all works OK, it is recognized, so I know my path is OK....

In the header of my `page.html` I have the following:

```
<script src="/static/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

From my app.yaml:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 1d
```

Comment: btw i also tried src="./static/jquery.js" and src="static/jquery.js" which both dont work when page is served from agg engine sdk but do work when page is uploaded directly from local hd...sorry if thats redundant info

Comment: The reason <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" ...> isnt sufficient for me is because I do must do lots of my coding off-line

Comment: What happens if you try to fetch http://localhost:8080/static/jquery.js ?

Comment: just tried it but didnt work --- I wonder if some one has made it work offline without using 
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/…; ...> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that all files you want to be recognized by the client's browser such `jquery.js` should be inside a directory that is ***inside the static directory.***

So the portion of the app.yaml file that relates to this should appear as follows:

```
- url: /jquery
  static_dir: static/jquery


- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 1d
```

what is key line that I now changed to make it work is where jquery stuff is inside static directory:  static_dir: static/jquery

so now in the header section of the page.html I have this working so I can work with the SDK off-line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.form.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you upload jquery.js with you app and set up a [static file handler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers) for it?

Comment: In my app.yaml I have the following, so I think I am OK with setting up a static file handler:


- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  expiration: 1d

Comment: You are right. All in needed to do was put the jquery.js in the correct static folder of the app. Sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 0):

For the second try this one

```
<script src="./static/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Double check your paths, and also check the weather of external scripts are they available.

Comment: I didnt understand this part of what you wrote "...check the weather of external scripts are they available." .. 

could you please explain what you mean?

I tried your suggest of ./static with but didnt work.

BTW. I have now gotten this to work:

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

But I would still like to recognize /static/jquery.js so I can work when off-line

So my main question now is how do i check if 'external scripts are available' ?

Comment: Yes, I mean to check are the external script available.

Comment: yes I tested it was available since jquery is recognized when I load the html page directly into the browser from my hard drive  --- it just doest work, using the same URLs when using the from app engine...

Answer (score 0):

or you can try referencing the jQuery file as

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: what you write work  - thanks - but I would still like to see it work from the /static directory so I can work with the SDK off-line